# model.eval() disables only dropout layers defined in outer class in Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, dropout

I am trying to reproduce the original transformer for machine translation in PyTorch.

```py
class Transformer(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, vocab_size_in, vocab_size_out, embedding_dim, n_heads, key_dim, value_dim, ffn_dim, n=10000,
                 eps=1e-5, padding_token_index=0, p_drop=0.1, n_encoder_layers=1, n_decoder_layers=1):
        super(Transformer, self).__init__()

        # parameters
        self.key_dim = key_dim
        self.n_heads = n_heads
        self.embedding_dim = embedding_dim
        self.eps = eps
        self.ffn_dim = ffn_dim
        self.padding_token_index = padding_token_index
        self.vocab_size_in = vocab_size_in

        # Embedding layers encoder
        self.embedding_layer_enc = EmbeddingLayer(vocab_size_in, embedding_dim, n)
        self.dropout_enc = nn.Dropout(p_drop)

        # Encoder layers
        self.encoder_layers = [EncoderLayer(embedding_dim, key_dim, value_dim, ffn_dim, n_heads, p_drop, eps)] * n_encoder_layers

        # Embedding layers decoder
        self.embedding_layer_dec = EmbeddingLayer(vocab_size_out, embedding_dim)
        self.dropout_dec = nn.Dropout(p_drop)

        # Decoder layers
        self.decoder_layers = [DecoderLayer(embedding_dim, key_dim, value_dim, ffn_dim, n_heads, p_drop, eps)] * n_decoder_layers

        # Linear output layer
        self.output_linear = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, vocab_size_out)

    def forward(self, input, target):
        # ...
```

As you can see there are two dropout layers defined here. Moreover, I have further dropout layers in `EncoderLayer` and `DecoderLayer`.

```py
class EncoderLayer(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, embedding_dim=512, key_dim=512, value_dim=512, ffn_dim=512, n_heads=8, p_drop=0.1, eps=1e-5):
        super().__init__()

        self.multi_head = MultiHeadAttentionLayer(n_heads, embedding_dim, key_dim, value_dim)
        self.dropout_multi_head = nn.Dropout(p_drop)
        self.norm_multi_head = LayerNormalization(embedding_dim, eps)
        self.FFN_in = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, ffn_dim)
        self.FFN_out = nn.Linear(ffn_dim, embedding_dim)
        self.dropout_FFN = nn.Dropout(p_drop)
        self.norm_FFN = LayerNormalization(embedding_dim, eps)

    def forward(self, source, mask=None):
        multi_head_out = self.multi_head(source, mask)  # shape = (n_sentences, len_sentence, embedding_dim)
        multi_head_out = self.dropout_multi_head(multi_head_out)
        multi_head_norm = self.norm_multi_head(source + multi_head_out)
        ffn_in = self.FFN_in(multi_head_norm)
        ffn_in = F.relu(ffn_in)
        ffn_out = self.FFN_out(ffn_in)
        ffn_out = self.dropout_FFN(ffn_out)
        enc_out = self.norm_FFN(multi_head_norm + ffn_out)

        return enc_out
```

I am testing my code in evaluation mode. The forward step takes source and target sequences of indices and outputs a tensor of probabilities for each word in the output sequence. So far, the testing function is simple, I just wanted to make sure when I input the same thing the output stays the same:

```
def translate_sentence(model, source, target, max_num_words=200):
        for i in range(max_num_words):
            model.eval()

            with torch.no_grad():

                output = model(source, target)
                print(output)
```

However, that does not happen. As suggested, I added:

```py
print(model.dropout_enc.training)
print(model.encoder_layers[0].dropout_multi_head.training)
```

In order to check if dropout layers are active or not, and the output is:

```
False
True
```

Therefore, `model.eval()` disables dropout layers defined in the `__init__` of Transformer, but not in its sublayers. Any idea on how to solve?

---

Solved: I had to use `nn.ModuleList`.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), e.g. how do you construct the model and what `SubLayer` looks like.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

The [`__repr__`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/nn/modules/dropout.py#L20-L21) method of [`nn.Dropout`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Dropout.html) doesn't output that kind of information. That's why it will show the same whatever the mode the layer is on.

It doesn't mean it isn't applied though, you can check for yourself!
You can check the mode of your sublayer or parent layer with the [`training`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#:%7E:text=Boolean%20represents%20whether%20this%20module%20is%20in%20training%20or%20evaluation%20mode.) attribute:

```
>>> model = nn.Dropout(0.5)
>>> model.training
True

>>> model.eval()
Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)

>>> model.training 
False
```

---

The reason why the mode is not propagated to your child layers is because you are using lists which means the layers are not registered as child modules. Instead, you should wrap your lists with [`nn.ModuleList`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ModuleList.html) for `encoder_layers` and `decoder_layers`.

Comment: Ok, I printed model.dropout.training and it returns False, but then I print model.sublayer.dropout_sublayer.training and it returns True. How can I put this in evaluation mode then?

Comment: You need to wrap your lists with `nn.ModuleList` or `nn.ModuleDict` for the encoder/decoder layers to be registered in the parent module. I have edited my answer above.